# Jquery Datatable drag and drop rows , Row reordering from json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatable

I am using: `jquery.dataTables.js` from: https://datatables.net

I want to do 2 things:

1. How can I make my rows be drag and drop? any ideas? or Row reordering
2. right now the rows is not following the order number like: 1,2,3,4,5, how can i make the rows follow the number orders?

I found this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/0308ctqp/ but I could not make work on my code.

Edit:
**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/9/) answer running here**:

see answer bellow

html:

```
<div class=" dashboard">
  <div class="col-md-8 no-padding">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option value="Filter by">Filter by country </option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="EUA">EUA</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Place</th>
         <th>Order</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    columns: [{
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'name'
    },{
      data: 'order'
    }]
  });

  $('#sel1').change(function() {
    if (this.value === "All") {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search('')
        .draw();
    } else {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/8/)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the reordring import required lib : (jquery-ui.js - jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js )

And for reordering order , when using `rowReordering` by default the first row is used to order table , so make the order field as first in column data , otherwise I think (It's possible to use dataTable.editor.js )

Bellow a working sniipet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clmDuyndua?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex){
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    },
    rowReorder: {
       dataSrc: 'order',
    },
    columns: [
      {
         data: 'order'
      },{
         data: 'name'
      },{
         data: 'place'
    }]
  });
 table.rowReordering();  
  
  
  $('#sel1').change(function() {
    if (this.value === "All") {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search('')
        .draw();
    } else {
      table
        .columns(1)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//mpryvkin.github.io/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/1.2.3/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>

<div class=" dashboard">
  <div class="col-md-8 no-padding">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option value="Filter by">Filter by country </option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="EUA">EUA</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Place</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: perfect, you are a genius

Comment: My pleasure @Raduken :)

Comment: does this works with jquery 3.0?  I tried now with jquery 3.0 and did not work :( https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: This is what I also looking for, Thank you!